# Problem with angular and Java Jersey API, with encode utf-8 whitespaces at the end not valid json

Tags: java, angular, jersey-2.0

I have a problem, when i try to do http get in angular, throw "Http failure during parsing", because the Json have some whitespaces characters at the end, i dont understand why the server return this.

there is some way, in which from angular can omit these characters before http.get do Json.parse , or someone knows why the server may be returning them. I am running with Tomcat 8.5. This whitespaces characters only occur when the response have special characters like "ñ" or "á,é,í,ó,ú"

Here upload two images of how the answer has whitespaces
https://ibb.co/Jtdy1Mp

https://ibb.co/W6QxGrc

This is an example of java rest service.

```
@Path("/plagas")
@Produces("application/json;charset=UTF-8") 
@Consumes("application/json;charset=UTF-8") 
public class PlagasController {
    @GET
    @Path("/{idTipoMonitoreo}")
    public Response consultar(@HeaderParam("token") String token, @PathParam(value="idTipoMonitoreo") long idTipoMonitoreo ) throws Exception {
        IntUsuarioGenericoManager usuarioGenericoManager = new ImpUsuarioGenericoManager();
        IntTiposMonitoreoPlagasManager tipoMonitoreoPlagasManager = new ImpTiposMonitoreoPlagasManager();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        try {
            UsuarioGenericoDTO usuario = usuarioGenericoManager.usuarioPorToken(token);
            TipoMonitoreoDTO tmDirecto = new TipoMonitoreoDTO();
            tmDirecto.setIdTipoMonitoreo(idTipoMonitoreo);
            List<TipoMonitoreoPlagasDTO> plagas = tipoMonitoreoPlagasManager.buscarTodoPorTipoMonitoreo(tmDirecto,usuario);
            return Response.ok().entity(gson.toJson(plagas)).build();
        }catch(ParseException e) {
            return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.serverError().build();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Those aren't whitespace characters, they're NULs (ASCII 0). You said they only appear when the response contains "special" characters like ñ etc. Does the number of NUL characters equal the number of "special" characters in the response?

Comment: Yes, sorry you are right, they are NULs. the number of Nuls characters is equal the number of "special" characters in the response

Answer (score 0):

You said that the number of NUL characters at the end of your JSON is equal to the number of "special" characters.

There is some disagreement between your Jersey server and your web app about how the response is encoded and/or what the content length means.

Let's say you have 10 characters in your response and 3 of them are "special."

- The number of *characters* in the response is 10.
- The number of *bytes* in the UTF-8 encoded response is 13, because the UTF-8 encoding encodes 7 of the characters are one byte and 3 of the characters as 2 bytes each (7 + 2*3 = 13).
- The *content-length* of the response is 13, since it's defined as the number of bytes.

(Someone will point out that the length of the UTF-8 encoded response isn't necessarily 13 bytes, because some of the special characters may be encoded as 3 or 4 bytes. But my objective isn't to get into the details of UTF-8 encoding but rather to call your attention to the difference between *characters* and *bytes*.)

Some possibilities:

- The client is interpreting the content-length as the number of *characters* to read rather than the number of *bytes*, so it reads 3 characters beyond the end of the response and fills in those characters with NUL.
- The server is allocating space for the UTF-8 encoded response (13 bytes) and setting content-length to 13, but is then is actually encoding the response as something else, like ISO-8559-1 ("Latin-1"), which produces a 10-byte response, leaving 3 NUL bytes at the end of the buffer.

Or there might be some other place in the code where bytes and characters are being mixed up. It's hard to say exactly where it's happening without having all the code.

What you should do is isolate each component and see if it's working properly. For example, you could use something like curl or Postman to test your server and make sure that it's actually sending UTF-8 encoded text, that the content-length is correct, etc.